# Could not start RStudio Server 0.99.893-x86_64

Tags: centos, installation, rstudio-server

I installed it a Centos 7 box. 
R studio server service could not start. 
I run the command

```
systemctl status rstudio-server.service
```

and it showed:

```
● rstudio-server.service - RStudio Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rstudio-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2016-01-28 20:18:20 ICT; 1min 6s ago
  Process: 48820 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jan 28 20:18:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service: control process exited, code=exited s...=203
Jan 28 20:18:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start RStudio Server.
Jan 28 20:18:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit rstudio-server.service entered failed state.
Jan 28 20:18:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service failed.
Jan 28 20:18:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 28 20:18:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for rstudio-server.service
Jan 28 20:18:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start RStudio Server.
Jan 28 20:18:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit rstudio-server.service entered failed state.
Jan 28 20:18:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service failed.
```

I installed and run an old version (rstudio-server-0.99.491-1.x86_64) on the same box without any problem.
How could I fix the issues?

Answer (score 2):

Although you asked this question 3 years ago, I think it's still necessary to share my solution to this problem.

I encounter this problem after I updated R.

The reason why you can not restart rstudio-server is that the PORT 8787 was been using by previous rserver. After knowing this, the solution is easy.
First, check the pid that was using PORT 8787

```
sudo netstat -anp | grep 8787

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8787            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      pid/rserver
```

Second, kill this pid (use your pid)

```
sudo kill -9 pid
```

Third, restart rstudio-server or reinstall resutio server package